# How to properly use stripInaccessible for PMD ApexCRUDViolation

Tags: apex, field-level-security, crud, pmd

On triggers I have some PMD ApexCRUDViolation errors. I see on the winter/spring 20 release notes a new apex function "stripinaccessible" to manage records/fields permissions.

Could you have some examples/recommandations to use properly this new function for enforce security for

1. SOQL
2. DML Operation
3. Volontary bypass user permission to system mode. Sometimes I want to use system mode for DML or SOQL, how properly do that in order that PMD doesn't catch this code as an error

Comment: What examples are you looking for that [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_with_security_stripInaccessible.htm) does not provide? I think just your last point isn't directly answered.

Comment: I have requested to include this new functions on PMD : https://github.com/pmd/pmd/issues/2210

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 & 2 are addressed in [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_with_security_stripInaccessible.htm)

> In this example, the user doesn’t have permission to create the Probability field of an Opportunity.
>
> ```
> List<Opportunity> opportunities = new List<Opportunity>{
>     new Opportunity(Name='Opportunity1'),
>     new Opportunity(Name='Opportunity2', Probability=95)
> };
>
> // Strip fields that are not creatable
> SObjectAccessDecision decision = Security.stripInaccessible(
>     AccessType.CREATABLE,
>     opportunities);
>
> // Print stripped records
> for (SObject strippedOpportunity : decision.getRecords()) {
>     System.debug(strippedOpportunity);
> }
>
> // Print modified indexes
> System.debug(decision.getModifiedIndexes());
>
> // Print removed fields
> System.debug(decision.getRemovedFields());
>
> //Lines from output log
> //|DEBUG|Opportunity:{Name=Opportunity1}
> //|DEBUG|Opportunity:{Name=Opportunity2}
> //|DEBUG|{1}
> //|DEBUG|{Opportunity={Probability}}
> ```

---

Looking at the PMD documentation for ApexCRUDViolation, the check isn't that your accessing fields via soql that the user doesn't have permissions for, its checking something like `!Schema.sObjectType.Contact.fields.Name.isUpdateable()` before modifying that field or calling an update on that object. I don't think PMD would use `stripInaccessible` as a valid check - someone would have to add it & I'm unsure how maintained PMD Apex is.

If you check the [raw java file](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/blob/master/pmd-apex/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/pmd/lang/apex/rule/security/ApexCRUDViolationRule.java) used for that [PMD check](https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_rules_apex_security.html#apexcrudviolation) you'll notice that it has a few specific keywords it checks for in a pattern - and `stripInaccessible` is not included in that list.

---

Finally, even when running in a `unshared`, system context with "full" access, if you run this method it would strip out user-inaccessible fields. All the documentations mention user permissions, not file or system permissions. I don't have a source for that however, I haven't tried it & would be wary of relying on this because its a beta class & function.

Comment: Thanks for the documentation reference. But with this example what is properly way to decide to not send DML operation because there is at minimum one error concerning the record lists ? 

"if(decision.getModifiedIndexes() > 0) {
 System.debug("Error");
} else { 
insert accList;
}"

Or maybe there is a try catch solution somewhere ?

Comment: Yeah, thats the pattern I would use - but would do something like add a `pageMessage` saying "User cannot create or modify this or related record" & return null to refresh the page. Depending on the field & the page you might be able to "fix" the problem in apex by removing some modified fields but I'd rather just shut the user down.